# AutoMapper does not work with defined rules

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, fluentvalidation

I'm developing a REST api. I implement automapper packets to compare the post model object with a correct user model object.

The problem is that I configured and use like service in the dependency injection, but ignore the defined rules.

```
IMapper mapper = CreateMapperStartUp(services);
```

Here I created the `IMapper` object:

```
private IMapper CreateMapperStartUp(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(conf =>
    {
        conf.AddProfile<MappingKey>();
    });

    IMapper mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
    return mapper;
}
```

I'm using a profile "MappingKey".

```
public class MappingKey : Profile
{
        public MappingKey()
        {
            CreateMap<CreateKeyViewModel, Key>().ReverseMap();
            CreateMap<UpdateKeyViewModel, Key>().ReverseMap();
        }
}
```

There I created the map method with post object models and key user objects. And finally my validator class with mapping rules.

```
public class CreateKeyValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateKeyViewModel>
{
    private readonly MysqlDAO _mysqlDAO;

    public CreateKeyValidator(MysqlDAO mysqlDAO)
    {
        _mysqlDAO = mysqlDAO;

        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotNull().Must(x => !_mysqlDAO.ExistId(x));
        RuleFor(x => x.Colour).NotNull().Length(2, 3);
        RuleFor(x => x.Date).NotNull().Length(2, 50);
    }
}
```

What is the problem and why the mapper pass object with null parameters?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, finally found the mistake. In this case the validation class wasn't defined by service on the StartUp. So using the fluentValidation method to create his own instance:

```
services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>());
```

And that's it. It works fine all the rules.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand. You create mapper. And do not use it anywhere (unfortunately ther is no using in code that you provide).

You call `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));`

But mapper that you created `IMapper mapper` and init it's profile, not used here. So, how your application will knows about mapper instance.

Is I correct? If not please provide more context.

I suppose you should write something like this:

```
IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
services.AddSingleton(mapper);
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, in the post I don't wrote the AddSingleton, but in the real pipeline it's like that.

```
private IMapper CreateMapperStartUp(IServiceCollection services) {
    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(conf =>
    {
        // conf.CreateMap<Key, CreateKeyViewModel>();
        conf.AddProfile<MappingKey>();
    });

    IMapper mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
    services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

    // services.AddSingleton(mapper);
    return mapper;
}
```

And when I'm adding the instance to the services, I need to access the registered instance of IMapper.

```
private void AddMysqlService(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = CreateLoggerFactory(services.BuildServiceProvider());
    IMapper mapper = CreateMapperStartUp(services);

    services.AddSingleton<IConnection<Key>>(new ConnectionMannager(Configuration.GetSection("mysqlDb"), loggerFactory));

    var connectionMnamagerInstance = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConnection<Key>>();
    services.AddSingleton<IService<Key>>(new MysqlService(mapper, connectionMnamagerInstance));
}
```